# How do I position clickable icon over (bottom right) images in flexbox grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to place an icon (somewhat like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q378c.jpg)) over the top of my flexbox image grid in my project, but I can't figure out how. It would be preferable if the icon was clickable so that the image could come up large when clicked or similar. Could someone please help with this?
Thanks!

Here's my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
.heading {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  line-height: 30vw;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-top: -10vw;
}

.galleryimg {
  margin: 9px;
  transition: filter 0.2s;
  filter: brightness(100%);
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.galleryimg:hover {
  filter: brightness(80%);
}

.responsive:hover {

}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(50, 50, 50), rgb(30, 30, 30));
  margin-top: -20px;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.headertitle {
  margin-top: -36vh;
  margin-left: 12vw;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: calc(13px + 2.5vw);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: lighter;
}

/* navbar */
nav {
  background: rgb(52, 52, 52);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: calc(18px + 6vh);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100vw;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 3.2vw;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1vh;

}
.navul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 5.5vh;
  height: 5.5vh;
  font-size: calc(15px + 0.25vh + 0.15vw);
}
.navuul a:visited, a:link, a:active
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 5.5vh;
    height: 5.5vh;
}
.navuul a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 5.5vh;
    height: 5.5vh;
}
.submit {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1.5vw;
}
.submit a {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.navimgdiv img {
    width: 0.8vw;
}

.navimgdiv {
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-left: 0.5vw;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1vw;
}

.navimgdiv img :hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
.navimgdiv a:visited, a:link, a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 5.5vh;
  height: 5.5vh;
}
/* navbar end */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pgallerystyles.css">
    <title> Photo Gallery </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="fullwidth"></div>
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="navimgdiv"><img src="logo.svg">Lumastock</a>
    <ul class="navul">
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Assesment Requirements</a></li>
        <li class="submit"><a href="#">Submit a photo</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<header></header>
<h1 class="headertitle">Image Gallery</h1>
    <main class="site-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="responsive"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400.jpg"></div>
        <div class="responsive"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600.jpg"></div>
        <div class="responsive"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600.jpg"></div>
        <div class="responsive"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400.jpg"></div>
        <div class="responsive"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400.jpg"></div>
        <div class="responsive"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400.jpg"></div>
        <div class="responsive"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400.jpg"></div>
        <div class="responsive"><img class="galleryimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400.jpg"></div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

Screenshot of the website: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Your images were not displaying so it was hard to work with the provided code, so here is a simple example that should help.

The div wrapping the images needs `position: relative`, then you can add `position: absolute` to the icon that gets clicked, directional rules let you dictate exactly where relative to the container div.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.clickable-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.clickable-icon:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  <span onClick="alert('ya clicked me!')" class="clickable-icon">X</span>
</div>
```